# jquery replaceWith not working on google chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, outerhtml

I am facing a strange problem with dynamically replacing controls using javascript in Google Chrome. The replaced controls dont show up in UI but when i use developer tools i am able to locate the replaced element but it does not show up until i close the developer tools. once i open and close developer tools the issue is no longer replicatable until i refresh the page.

This happens only in cases where i am trying to replace outerHTML of an element.

I first tried using `jquery's replaceWith` api, that dint help so i switched to the following script -

```
function chromeOuterHTML(oldElem, outerhtml)
{
var el = document.createElement('div');
el.innerHTML = outerhtml;
var parentNode = oldElem.parentNode;
var range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(el);
        var documentFragment = range.extractContents();
        parentNode.insertBefore(documentFragment, oldElem);
        parentNode.removeChild(oldElem);
}
```

I dont think that its a problem with my javascript since the problem is specific to chrome and also happens in only certain cases.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You will definitely get a solution faster if you can post a link to an example page!

Comment: A few other thoughts: Ranges are interesting beasts - they can span several elements between their start and end points, so they don't necessarily select DOM nodes cleanly. That _shouldn't_ be a problem in your case, but you never know.

Comment: I have also seen odd behaviour when dealing with documentFragments which have more than one top-level node. I can't remember the specifics, but I found they behaved a lot better when the fragment was contained in a single top-level node.

Comment: the problem is that i am not able to replicate the issue in a sample page. even tried saving the existing page to replicate the issue but i am not able to.

Comment: I have also tried jquery's replaceWith api, that dint help as well. in my case all the elements i replace are directly under the body tag. I have also seen that this issue happens predominantly but not always in popup windows

Answer (score 1):

More a diagnostic tool than a solution, but have you tried delaying your insertBefore?

```
function chromeOuterHTML(oldElem, outerhtml)
{
var el = document.createElement('div');
el.innerHTML = outerhtml;
var parentNode = oldElem.parentNode;
var range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(el);
        var documentFragment = range.extractContents();
            setTimeout(function () {    
                parentNode.insertBefore(documentFragment, oldElem);
                parentNode.removeChild(oldElem);
    }, 1);
}
```

In some situations (that I don't fully understand), DOM manipulations can fail if they happen in too quick a succession. This modification will delay (only by 1ms) the insert - it's possible that it will make a difference. It's also possible it'll do nothing!